# will_paginate not working in a certain view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

I have the following code in my view file

```
<div id="articles">
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<h2>
<%= link_to r.univ_name, "#" %>
</h2>
<div class="info">
<b><%= r.location %>, <%= r.state %></b> <br/>
</div>
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
<div class="content"><p><%= r.description %><p></div>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @results %>
```

I included

```
@results = Result.search(params[:query], page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
```

in `results_controller.rb` file. I have around 8 records in my results table however the view lists out all the records instead of limiting them to 4 per page. Can somebody suggest where i am doing it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think it should be `Result.search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are right!

Comment: @ArupRakshit Still appears the same

Comment: What is the output of `@results` ? I mean ` Result.search(params[:query]` ?

Comment: Post your `method` of your `controller` where you are giving `pagination`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `paginate` method of `will_paginate` gem to implement *pagination*.

```
@results = Result.search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
```

Make sure you are setting `@results` instance variable in the Controller's `action` which renders your view with

```
<%= will_paginate @results %>
```

Comment: @user3317862 Can you share the code for `search` method, also include the server log generated for this request. Add it in the question.

Comment: It works now. There was a if else condition on listing out the results. I figured it out. However, the answer was helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`Basic will_paginate use`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use), your code is wrong. It should be as below :

```
Result.search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
```

Comment: +1 for being first to give the correct answer (in your comment).